# Drag to change position of a 3D model object in Three.js scene

Tags: javascript, 3d, drag-and-drop, three.js, html5-canvas

I am using an example of three.js in which I can rotate, zoom in and zoom out the 3D object but I need to change its position by dragging. I am stuck in this for a very long time any help would be appreciated.

here is the link of example:

http://public.manuelwieser.com/female_croupier_2013-03-26.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966055/three-js-drag-collada-files/32986792#32986792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check on `mousedown` if it intersects with object. If it does intersect we will drag the object. If it does not intersect we will rotate.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b5cd4o54/)